# the dual of the LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

$max \sum _{j=1}^nc_jx_j$

$\sum _{j=1}^na_jx_j\le b$  where $a_j, b$ are real numbers (not vectors)

$x_j\ge 0$ for all $j$

Could you please help to write its dual?

Attempt:
$min \sum _{j=1}^nu_j*b$

$a*u_j\ge c_j$ for each $j$

$u_j$ is unit vector where jth component is 1.

Comment: There is no variables in your dual

Answer (score 2):

$$\min\limits_{y} \quad Z=y\, b$$
subject to:
$$
a_1y\ge c_1\\
…\\
a_n y \ge c_n\\
y\ge 0
$$